# Finding a character in a string using an index array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I have a string to parse. I managed to use a method to find the indices of a substring. Here's the code:

```
indexArray = []
myString.to_enum(:scan, /(\n)/i).map do
  indexArray.push [$`.size]                                         #`
end
#indexArray = [0,2,3,4,5,6]
myString[indexArray[1]] # => no implicit conversion of Array into Integer (TypeError)
```

I tried using `to_i`, but it seems like broken logic. Any insight is appreciated. If I uncomment the second to the last line, making `indexArray` an array of integers, it works. I am wondering why I can get a character at an index using a basic array, but not the array derived from this method.

Comment: ``indexArray.push [$`.size]`` pushes _another array_ onto `indexArray`, so you end up with something like `[[0],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]]`. You probably want ``indexArray.push $`.size``.

Comment: Adding an example would help quite a bit in solving this since it would allow us to see what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Not at my machine right now but thank you @Stefan! This is most likely the solution

Comment: I confirm that was the solution. Thank you @Stefan

Comment: @Stefan can you please make an answer out of your comment so this question can be closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should use `snake_case` instead of `camelCase` for method names and variables. The following code is changed accordingly.

This line:

```
index_array.push [$`.size]
```

will create a new array with a single element `` $`.size `` and push that onto `index_array`.

You'll end up with a nested array like this: (you can inspect the array via `p index_array`)

```
index_array #=> [[0], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
```

This can be easily fixed by just pushing `` $`.size `` (without the array):

```
index_array.push $`.size
```

Furthermore, your code can be simplified:

```
index_array = my_string.to_enum(:scan, /\n/).map { $`.size }
```

- `map` already returns an array containing the elements returned by the given block.
- the capture group around `\n` is not used and therefore not needed.
- the `i` flag is superfluous because there's only one `\n`.